# CUDA - copy a struct with an array to the gpu and back

Tags: arrays, struct, cuda

I have the nodes of an octree stored in an array and pos_childs point to the array position where the childnode is. How do I get a struct like this to the gpu, access it and get it back from the gpu properly? I can't use unified memory due to hardware restrictions.

```
typedef struct Octree
{
    //data
    unsigned pos_childs[8];
}octree_t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with an array of structures that *don't* contain embedded pointers to dynamically allocated data is not much different than working with an array of basic types.

Here's a worked example showing an array of your struct being initialized on the host, passed to the device, modifed on the device, and returned to the host:

```
$ cat t690.cu
#include <iostream>

const int dsize = 5;
const int nTPB = 256;

typedef struct Octree
{
    //data
    unsigned pos_childs[8];
}octree_t;


__global__ void kernel(Octree *data, size_t n){

  int idx=threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < n)
    data[idx].pos_childs[4] = data[idx].pos_childs[3];
}


int main(){

  Octree *h_data, *d_data;
  h_data = new Octree[dsize];
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, dsize*sizeof(Octree));
  for (int i = 0; i < dsize; i++) {h_data[i].pos_childs[3] = i; h_data[i].pos_childs[4] = 0;}
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, dsize*sizeof(Octree), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  kernel<<<(dsize+nTPB-1)/nTPB,nTPB>>>(d_data, dsize);
  cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, dsize*sizeof(Octree), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < dsize; i++) std::cout << h_data[i].pos_childs[4] << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -o t690 t690.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t690
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
0 1 2 3 4
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me quite a lot.